# Reading mocked ServletOutputStream from println

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I have an HttpServlet that I'm trying to write tests for and have mocked the ServletOutputStream: `ServletOutputStream outputStream = mock(ServletOutputStream.class);`. I need to get what's written to outputStream in the servlet that used `println`. ie, in the servlet, I have code like:

```
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutpuStream();
out.println("foo");
```

So, I would want to test for "foo." I've tried to say `when(outputStream.println()).then...`, but this doesn't work since println() is a void method. I've also investigated HttpServletResponseWrappers, but have been unable to find a solution there. Ideas? I'm using Mockito.

Comment: What's the mocking API you're using?

Comment: Do you want to make sure that "foo" is written to the stream? That would be (in Mockito): verify(outputStream).println(eq("foo"));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see if "foo" is passed to the println method you could do:

```
verify(outputStream).println(eq("foo"));
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. I'd like to add, that this specifies that I see "foo" exactly once. `verify(outputStream, atLeastOnce()).println(eq("foo"));` for "foo" >= 1 time being valid.

Comment: Note that you don't need the `eq()` here; you can just write `verify(outputStream).println("foo");` or `verify(outputStream, atLeastOnce()).println("foo");`

Comment: What package is verify and eq from?